# How to upload a big file with little php memory?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I'm developing a web (html, php, js, mysql) application where users can upload videos to the server, the server stores them in a folder and add an entry into the database.

Is intended to be useful to local tv stations or media producers as a media manager to catalog videos.

The software is intended to be installed on a local server, so you can upload/download big video files in seconds.

The problem is I don't know how to handle such a big upload. I've increased all the settings in my PHP.ini (post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, all scrip-time related and also the script memory_limit to 2G which is the maximum the system allows me to put without crashing.

I can upload files up to 1GB with no problems. Between 1GB and 2GB I get this message:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of [filesize] bytes exceeds the limit of 1073741824 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

Where [filsezize] is the size of the file I'm uploading in bytes.

And with files over 2GB, the upload process terminates when the browser has uploaded 2GB and the error is allways:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 2147483647 bytes exceeds the limit of 1073741824 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

I think this is happening because the server doesn't have enough memory, but with users possibly uploading 20GB files, adding memory isn't a solution.

Is there a way where I can upload REALLY big files without using much system memory?

EDIT: Even with a different technology. JavaScript can do it? Anything. But as simple as possible.

¿How does YouTube handles his uploads?

The server is a Synology Diskstation so I have lots of disk space but not much cpu or memory.

Thanks! ;)

Comment: php is incredibly stupid for uploads. you need to have a memory_limit larger than the file being upload, plus there's post size limits in both apache and php. if you need "large" files uploaded, then don't use PHP to handle them.